# VS Code Merge Editor doesn't get populated

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-merge-conflict

I tried to git pull but couldn't because I got conflicts. There is a button on the file saying **"Resolve in Merge Editor"**.

When I click it, **Merge Edito**r opens (the three-window one) but it never goes beyond loading state.

I updated VS code, toggled and untoggled **Git: Merge Editor** check box, closed VS Code but nothing helps.
The editor tab is still at the loader state (blue color dash traveling from left to right).

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Check also your Output Panel to see if any of the output channels there have any related-looking info.